Reduced device support warning message
How do we fix the "Reduced device support warning message" when trying to publish the FireTV app?
Error message "Reduced device support warning message" How can we update the libraries to reflect all the latest devices. Is this FireTV builder template still being supported?

Similar to: Device support removed warning coming when updating app on playstore Android
